# Adding a dynamic textview to a fragmment crashes app

Tags: java, android, dynamic, fragment

I have been trying to add a textview dynamically to my fragment but it is causing the app to crash, the below code works in a non-fragment activity I just cant get it work in a fragment.  At the moment my code uses just on textview, but it will eventually return many from a database, hence why I need it to be dynamically created.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View theView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_batches, container, false);
    context=getActivity();

    //Dynamically create Elements
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams SVView = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    LinearLayout SV = (LinearLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listBatchesRelative);
    TextView batchName = new TextView(context);
    int i = 1;
    batchName.setId(Integer.valueOf(i));
    batchName.setText("Dynamic Input view");
    batchName.setLayoutParams(SVView);
    SV.addView(batchName);

return theView
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
View theView;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 theView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_batches, container,false);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams SVView = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
LinearLayout SV = (LinearLayout)theView .findViewById(R.id.listBatchesRelative);
TextView batchName = new TextView(theView.getContext);
int i = 1;
batchName.setId(Integer.valueOf(i));
batchName.setText("Dynamic Input view");
batchName.setLayoutParams(SVView);
SV.addView(batchName);
return theView
```

Comment: Thanks for that worked a treat, for others wanting to use this code there was just one amendment theView.getContext  needed to be theView.getContext()  .  Much appreciated Jaswinder.

Comment: ya that i write by hand so thats mistak bcz me at home  so dont have eclips on my home system but thanx for all